# (TLS v.1.0)Along with ServerHello comes something else

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, starttls, tls1.0

Instead, something else is sent from the ServerHello(2). I can not understand what it is. It looks like a certificate, but it's one. Then the certificate chain is sent. I using WireShark. Help! To help me, I sent the entire packet in bytes

```
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
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zscU4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming or development question and does not really belong on SO.

The first frame contains all of the ServerHello message but only the first part of the Certificate message, which is the next message. Because of the size of this Certificate message (mostly due to the size of the certificates in it) it doesn't fit in the space available in the first frame; it requires a second complete frame and part of a third frame as well to contain the data. Wireshark can't decode the message until it gets to the end of the message, which is in the third frame -- #70 in your example. (You filtered the second frame, #69, out of your display.) Your message list pane shows that frame #70 is decoded as Certificate plus ServerHelloDone; the detail display for the Certificate message will actually contain data from frames #68 #69 AND #70. The detail display for the TCP layer will confirm this. The content of the Certificate message from the server is indeed the certificates making up the server's certificate chain.